# In what base should we express the transformation coefficient for a wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fourier-transform

We have, for example, that $\psi(p) = \int e^{ixp/\hbar} \psi(x)\, dx$, which isn't really hard to derive.
But in what base should we express $e^{ixp/\hbar}$? In the $x$ or the $p$ basis?
Also, what are we integrating over? I suppose if we're in the $x$ basis, we go from negative infinity to infinity, but what about the reverse, from the $x$ to the $p$ basis? Do we integrate/sum over all possible momenta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to remember this is to realize that the resolution of the identity for discrete bases
$$
\hat{1}=\sum_n \vert n\rangle\langle n\vert
$$
is a sum over *all* basis states.  The continuous case replaces the discrete sum by a continuous sum so that
\begin{align}
\hat{1}&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \vert x\rangle \langle x\vert\, ,\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dp \vert p\rangle \langle p\vert  
\end{align}
with $\langle x\vert p\rangle = \langle p\vert x\rangle^* = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}} e^{ipx/\hbar}$.  This is just a continous sum (*i.e.* an integral) over *all* basis states.

Note there that with these definitions direct and inverse Fourier transforms are symmetric in the placement and powers of the $2\pi$ factors.  The extra $\hbar$ comes in because the FT is usually defined using $k=p/\hbar$ rather than $p$.

Comment: Ok, but that's not what I asked. I asked for that exponential coefficient, should we have x and p in what basis? Do we just express them each in their respective basis?

Comment: @Dah_Fisicist I don't understand your comment.  I have it clearly that $\langle x\vert p\rangle = \langle p\vert x\rangle^* = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}} e^{ipx/\hbar}$ so if you express $\vert p\rangle$ in the $x$-basis you get for instance $\langle x\vert p\rangle =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}} e^{ipx/\hbar}$.  This coefficient is a *number* (it comes from the scalar product $\langle x\vert p\rangle$) not an operator.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand that, I thought that x and p were operators, not variables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The expression
$$\tilde{\psi}(p)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx\,\exp(-ipx/\hbar)\psi(x)$$
(using a slightly different notation from in the question*) is just an ordinary integral, and it tells you how to change the basis.  The wave function $\psi(x)$ is the wave function in the position representation, $\psi(x)=\langle x|\phi\rangle$.  What the equation says is that the Fourier transform, $\tilde{\psi}(p)$, is the wave function in the momentum representation, $\psi(p)=\tilde{\psi}(p)=\langle p|\psi\rangle$.

Since the form taken by an eigenstate of position with eigenvalue $x_{0}$ in the momentum representation is $\langle p|x_{0}\rangle=\exp(-ipx_{0}/\hbar)$, the Fourier transform formula can actually be seen as an expansion of the momentum-state wave function $\tilde{\psi}(p)$ in a complete set of position eigenstates.  The function $\tilde{\psi}(p)$ is a $x$ states (an integral instead of a sum, since the eigenvalues of $p$ form a continuous, rather than discrete, spectrum), with the weight of each eigenstate given by $\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle$. Note that this means the whole formula can be rewritten as
$$\langle p|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx\,\langle p|x\rangle\langle x|\psi\rangle=\langle p|\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx\,|x\rangle\langle x|\right)|\psi\rangle,$$
which makes sense, since
$${\bf 1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx\,|x\rangle\langle x|$$
is just the identity operator, expressed as a integral over a complete set of position eigenstates.

The inverse relation is in integral over all $p$, to get $\psi(x)$ from $\tilde{\psi}(p)$,
$$\psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dp\,\exp(ipx/\hbar)\tilde{\psi}(p).$$

*I have included tilde to mark the Fourier transform, but it is not necessary.  The limits of integration are also given, and the constant factor ensures that if $\psi(x)$ is normalized, then so is $\tilde{\psi}(p)$.  Most significantly, I have corrected the signs in the exponentials to match the usual conventions of quantum mechanics.

Comment: Ok, but that's not what I asked. I asked for that exponential coefficient, should we have x and p in what basis? Do we just express them each in their respective basis?

Comment: @Dah_Fisicist I'm afraid that, as best I understand what you are saying, what I wrote should actually answer that question about the basis.  I guess I don't follow quite what you want to ask.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. It's just that I thought that the x and p in the exponent were to be taken as operators, not variables.